# R `dnbinom` giving different results than Python `scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf` even after accounting for different parameterization

Tags: python, r, statistics

I am trying to translate my colleague's R code into Python. It involves making a calculation with a negative binomial distribution's probability mass function, but the issue is that R's `dnbinom` uses a differing parameterization from Python's `scipy.stats.nbinom.pmf`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888226/cdf-of-a-negative-binomial-with-mu-and-alpha-in-python) question and it's answer, given R's `mu` (mean) and `size`(dispersion), I should be able to get Scipy's `n` and `p` with the following code:

```
 p = 1 / (1 + size * mu)
 n = 1 / size
```

However, if I assume `convert_params` does the above calculation and apply it like this:

```
 from scipy.stats import nbinom
 n, p = convert_params(15, 0.463965)
 nbinom.pmf(3, n, p)
```

I get `0.036`, whereas if I do this in R:

```
 dnbinom(3, mu=15, size=0.463965)
```

I get `0.05`.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Have I used an incorrect formula to change the parameterization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from R's documentation,

> *size*    -- target for number of successful trials, or dispersion parameter (the shape parameter of the gamma mixing distribution). Must be strictly positive, need not be integer.

and from python:

> *n* is the number of successes. The number of successes *n* may also be specified in terms of a
> "dispersion", "heterogeneity", or "aggregation" parameter. ...

> The mean *mu* is related to the probability of success as
> `p = n/(n + mu)`

Thus you need to directly equate python's `n` to R's `size`:

```
mu, size = 15, 0.463965
scipy.stats.nbinom(n = size, p = 1/(1 + mu/size)).pmf(3)
0.050034315664281
```

---

```
dnbinom(3, mu=15, size=0.463965)
[1] 0.05003432
```

Comment: Ah, I see thank you! I believe the confusion comes from the fact that there isn't a clear consensus on what exactly the 'dispersion' parameter means. A few of the equivalent parameterizations of the distribution seem to use the term 'dispersion'.